# Filter grayscale on xul image turns it square

Tags: css, firefox-addon, xul

I'm trying to use the `filter:grayscale(1)` technique to grayscale an image. It works fine on the web but when I try it on my XUL image it's failing. It's turning it into a blurry square.

This is the before:
[image]

This is the after:
[image]

And here's a picture of the DOM inspection, my element is anonymous element.

[image]

Any ideas? That would be awesome! Thanks!

Edit:
I cant get code to replicate this outside for my addon but this is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window id="yourwindow" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <box class="profilist-tbb" >
                <image class="toolbarbutton-icon"  style="list-style-image: url(chrome://browser/skin/places/query.png)"/>
                <image class="profilist-badge"  style="filter:grayscale(1);transform:translate(-7px,14px) scale(.8);" src="chrome://branding/content/icon16.png"/>
                <box flex="1">
                    <stack class="profilist-display-stack" flex="1">
                    <html:input class="profilist-input"  style="display:none" />
                    <label class="toolbarbutton-text" crop="right" flex="1"  value="rawr"/>
                    </stack>
                </box>
            </box>
</window>
```

I also worked around it by putting the grayscale on the box element above it which makes everything inside grayscale, not just this badge icon, but I'll have to live with it till I can replicate it :(

Comment: I have a block of text I normally cut & paste requesting code from questions where they are [asking for debugging help, but don't provide any code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but I know *you know this is needed* because it makes providing help possible/much easier and you help people here by answering questions.  Please [edit] the question to include a MCVE. The problem could be anything from a bug in your implementation to a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=grayscale), but without code it is not possible for us to duplicate/test.

Comment: Thanks Mayken I'll put something together now :)

Comment: While it is a good idea to explore why this is happening, is there a reason that you are using the `filter:grayscale(1)` function instead of providing a sprite with the grayed-out image pre-computed? Providing the sprite and just shifting the image to display the grayed-out version is significantly less compute intensive than computing it on the fly. While it is not that much processing, there are situations where every little bit counts. You are transitioning a known image to a known grayscale image. Having a sprite with both images, is probably the way to go (Firefox does it this way).

Comment: Yes thanks Mayken for that q. I'm using it because the badges are supplied by user, so they can use any image they want :) Man i couldn't replicate this its so absolutely weird. I removed the filter grayscale from the image element and put it on the box around it, which makes everything else grayscale too but its the only way without getting this to turn blurry square. I couldn't replicate it but i posted code that I thought should replicate it. Would you have time to install my addon and look it for replication? I understand if no, it would need chatt, i have irc and teamviewer if you can :)

Comment: @Noitidart can you upload somewhere that icon?

Comment: Thanks @paa you mean this one: http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v135/noitidart/youtube-16_zps49b3e595.png?t=1426361671

Comment: I asked for the original icon just in case something weird was happening with the alpha channel. I tested it and the filter is applied as expected. Maybe some other rule is interfering?

Comment: Thanks @paa yeah its definitely some rule, cuz if i remove the class then it looks good. Ill work on finding that and report back :)